# Meteor Server-side variable persist between methods

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am building a simple Meteor-Angular 1 application and I am having a trouble to make my variable 'var conn' persist between methods in server.

Meteor code:

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';

var name;

    Meteor.methods({
        'setName': function () {
           name = 'Harry';
        },

        'getName': function () {
            console.log(name);
            });
        }
    });
```

If I am calling setName and getName from the same template in Angular then name persists. If I set name in one template but call getName in another template, then name is 'undefined'. I came with Java background and don't know how to make meteor class persist as the same object between Angular templates. Thank you very much for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Store it in a collection in MongoDB.
2. Use a global variable defined in a `/server/xxx.js` file.
3. Other server side persistence tools. Maybe https://github.com/lmaccherone/node-localstorage?

For alt 2, you could create a dictionary object and scope the data to the client connection by using the `connection.id` from `Meteor.onConnection()` [[Docs]](https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#Meteor-onConnection).

Answer (score 0):

i'm surprised it works at all. if that code is indeed running on the server, it's invoked in a new context on each call. if you want your data persisted, you need to persist in the database.